# Value of type 'StartMorgagesViewPage2' has no member 'pdfData2'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, writetofile

I created a variable called pdfData :

```
 var pdfData: NSData {
    let result = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(result, frame, nil)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return result }
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    layer.renderInContext(context)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    return result
 }
```

but then when I reference it:

```
   self.pdfData.writeToURL(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Page2.pdf"), atomically: true) // what it is saved as


    self.pdfData.writeToFile("Page2.pdf", atomically: false)
```

I get two errors 'Value of type 'StartMorgagesViewPage2' has no member 'pdfData2'. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit


class StartMorgagesViewPage2: UIView {

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {

        var gameTimer = NSTimer!()
        gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "screenshot", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


        /*  label.text = "\(instructedbyvalue)"
         accountnumberlabel.text = "\(accountnumbersvalue)" //(boo) //"boooooo"
         applicantslabel.text = "\(applicantsvalue)"
         propertyaddresslabel.text = "\(propertyaddressvalue)"
         eircodedetails.text = "\(eircodedetailsvalue)"
         */


        //Saving


    }


    func screenshot() {
        print("screenshot")

        var pdfData: NSData {
            let result = NSMutableData()
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(result, frame, nil)
            guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return result }
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            layer.renderInContext(context)
            UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
            return result
        }




        self.pdfData.writeToURL(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Page2.pdf"), atomically: true) // what it is saved as


        self.pdfData.writeToFile("Page2.pdf", atomically: false)
        print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path!)




    }




}
```

Here's a picture of the errors: [image: my errors] .

I can't think of a reason this could happen. I've tried Cleaning, Building and running the app.

Comment: Move the `pdfData` declaration out of your `screenshot` function – or omit the `self` (which you should usually do anyway), depending on what you're trying to do here (whether you want a calculated property or not).

Comment: Thanks, when I removed self. it worked . @originaluser2 Do you want to post that as the answer?

Comment: Sure thing! I only didn't go ahead initially as I wasn't sure whether you wanted a calculated property or just a calculated variable. Glad I was of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access your `pdfData` through using `self` – but `pdfData` isn't an instance member of `self`, it's just a plain old variable (albeit a calculated one).

The solution therefore is to simply remove the `self`:

```
pdfData.writeToFile("Page2.pdf", atomically: false)
```

You should also note that you should prefer to use `self` implicitly when referring to instance members (properties or methods) while in that class, as it makes your code more readable. For example – using `someMethodCall()` instead of `self.someMethodCall()`.